# Listen to specific hardware on Linux

Tags: java, linux, input, debian

I'm working on a some kind of ID card reader post-processor. Here is my configuration: I have a Ubuntu/Debian PC with a hw keyboard installed and accessed by remote screen. This PC will have multiple HID contact-less card readers connected (not at once).

I need my Java application to listen only to these readers and not to HW keyboard or TTY from screen.

```
public static void main(args){
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true){
        s.readline();
    }
}
```

I've read something about Linux multiseat and configuring udev to set readers to specific seat but how should i do that if the readers are from multiple vendors and how should i assign this java process to listen on specific seat?

Comment: I would run the Java application in the background (e.g. using `batch`) and redirect its stdin to `/dev/null` and use explicit file names to access the ID card. So your `main` would e.g. recieve `-cardreader=/dev/usb/cardreader32` or whatever (e.g. `-config=/etc/yourapp.conf` where the card reader is mentionned in configuration file `/etc/yourapp.conf` ...). And multiseat seems completely unrelated to your question.

Comment: could you be more specific about the card reader part? i can redirect the stdin but then it does not recieve anything

Comment: You should explain much more about the actual device (even the hardware), how it is configured and seen on the Linux system, etc...

Comment: The device i'm connecting is a RFID HID reader. it connects itself to `/dev/input` and i can read it with `cat` on `/dev/input/event0` fine. But if i point my java Scanner to that file it reads nothing. If i swipe the card it writes output to current focus window. I need this to be redirected to java application only